# How to have multiple base routes in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Consider the following:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home.index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

Route::group(['domain' => 'thechildandthepoet' . env('CONNECTION')], function() {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'thechildandthepoet.home', 'uses' => 'GameController@index']);
});
```

When I go to `thechildandthepoet.example.local` It shows me the contents of

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home.index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

completely by passing the fact that I told it which controller to use.

The link looks like: `<li><a href="{{ route('thechildandthepoet.home') }}">The Child And The Poet</a></li>`

**any idea why this doesn't work?**

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's router executes the **first route that matches given URL**.

You don't specify the domain for your first route, therefore it matches all domains. The second route, even though it matches the URL as well, is ignored.

Reorganize your **routes.php** file, put the routes that specify the domain at the beginning and keep the most generic routes at the end.